# Button refuses to work

Tags: asp.net, button

I have a standard button which should call a method but it just refuses to work and I can't figure out why.

ASP code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button 
            ID="UploadButton" runat="server" onclick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Change Logo" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordLabel.Visible = true;
            PasswordLabel.Text = "TEST Before";
            Image_Inserting(this);
            PasswordLabel.Text = "TEST After";

        }
```

I just added the textbox methods to test it but it doesn't seem to be posting back (even when I remove Image_Inserting call). All other buttons work fine so I don't know why this one won't work.

EDIT: Whole page- Button code towards the bottom

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Standardmaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VendorAccount.aspx.cs" Inherits="PetShopParadise.Vendor_Pages.VendorAccount" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style10
        {
            color: #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Account Details</h2>

    <div id="RegistrationDiv">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                Phone_Number:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Phone_NumberTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Phone_Number") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                Phone_Number:
                <asp:TextBox ID="Phone_NumberTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Phone_Number") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Name:
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Address:
                <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
                <br />
                Phone Number:
                <asp:Label ID="Phone_NumberLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Phone_Number") %>' />
                <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Edit Details" CommandName="Edit" />
                    <br />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PetShopParadiseConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Address], [Phone_Number] FROM [Vendors] WHERE ([VendorID] = @VendorID)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="VendorID" SessionField="ID" Type="Decimal" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <br />
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" style="text-align:left;">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow4" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server">Password</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordBox" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        id="RequiredFieldValidator5"
                        runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="PasswordBox"
                        Display="None"
                        Forecolor="Red"
                        ErrorMessage="Please enter a password." />
                        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow ID="TableRow5" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell9" runat="server">Re-Enter Password</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordCheckBox" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                        id="RequiredFieldValidator6"
                        runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="PasswordCheckBox"
                        Display="None"
                        Forecolor="Red"
                        ErrorMessage="Please re-enter your password." />
                    </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:Label 
            ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password" CssClass="style10"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="PasswordButton" 
            runat="server" Text="Update Password" onclick="PasswordButton_Click" /><br />


            <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PetShopParadiseConnectionString %>" 
            onselecting="SqlDataSource2_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Vendors" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Vendors] SET [Password]=@passwordhash WHERE ([VendorID] = @VendorID)" OnUpdating="Parameters_Updating">
            <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Password" />
            <asp:SessionParameter name="VendorID" sessionfield="ID" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <br /><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button 
            ID="UploadButton" runat="server" onclick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Change Logo" /></div></asp:Content>



                    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="bannerContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: do you have some JS on the page :

Comment: try with the debugger and not with the TextBox output. Either if you put a breakpoint in the method above or Debug.Write("...") do you see anything in the output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: what type is PasswordLabel ? is it textbox with password ? please update.

Comment: Nope, no javascript. And PasswordLabel is just a standard label used to display normal text.

I tried with the debugger too, it doesn't even enter the UploadButton_Click method.

Comment: How do you know it's not doing PostBack? Did you try to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is causing other (possibly hidden) validation to run.  Make sure to set **CausesValidation** to *false*.

Comment: Since it is not registering clicks, you can assume that JS is blocking.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot. May I ask how a button can have hidden validation? (Still new to asp and still figuring out the kinks)

Comment: Asp.Net WebForms is a strange monster... sometimes there can be hidden views that are still validated since the whole page is in one form.  For example, the form still includes all of the update markup up above, so the button, which is in the form, will validate that form unless you say explicitly not to. My avdice to you, go to Asp.Net MVC and never look back :) your life will be much easier (and higher paid...).

Comment: @naspinski that's misleading advice. I actually agree that generically MVC is a better way in terms of the markup in the broswer, but forms is a very effective way of solving a lot of problems very quickly.

Comment: @Kentz if you're doing validation on complex forms you need to look at validation groups which will allow you to constrain what gets validated on which postback event.

Answer (score 0):

quote : 
*I just added the textbox methods *

I guess our trying to update a Password textBox which you can't.

only by :

```
PasswordLabel .Attributes["value"] = "aaa";
```

Comment: It's just a normal label that I used with the debugger to see if it actually enters the method, but it doesn't seem to be registering the mouseclick and calling the method.

Comment: can you upload the whole page directive on the top lines ?

Comment: sorry but youll have also to upload the master page code. ( aspx)

Comment: Naspinksi managed to solve the problem, it seems there was some hidden validation going on. Thanks for your help though :)